# How to clean heated car seats

Tags: cleaning, seat

My car has heated seats so it has all these little ventilation holes in them

[image: heated seats closeup]

A child spilled her drink in the seat and some of it seeped through the holes. What would be the best way to ensure that all of the drink has been removed?

Comment: I’d suggest using your favourite fabric cleaner (washing powder and warm water would be fine) and scrub gently with a soft brush to make sure you get into the holes.  There’s no danger of electrocution, if that’s a concern.